# Set custom legend item symbol (or icon) in HIghcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to change the default highcharts legend symbol to my own custom one.
I wish to have a font-awesome icon next to the legend label.
for that, Iv'e thought about labelformatter:

```
labelFormatter: function () {
                    var on  = '<g><text x="0" y="0" style="color:'+this.color+';font-family:FontAwesome">&#xf14a;</text></g> ' + this.name;
                    var off   = '<g><text x="0" y="0" style="color:'+this.color+';font-family:FontAwesome">&#xf0c8;</text></g> ' + this.name;

                    return  this.iconState ? on : off;
                }
```

that actually let me add the icon as I wanted, but now my probelm is the following: when clicking on the legend items, the icons remain in the original color and do not become gray like the labels.
Iv'e thought about re-rendering the legend when a click event is fired (using legendItemClicked), but I havnn't found anything that works out.

Does anyone know how can I manage re-rendering the legend?

OR

How Its even possible to set the symbol to my own?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your custom symbol by adding this information to Highcharts symbol arrays, like in the example:

```
 Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.cross = function (x, y, w, h) {
    return ['M', x, y, 'L', x + w, y, 'z'];
};
if (Highcharts.VMLRenderer) {
    Highcharts.VMLRenderer.prototype.symbols.cross = Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.cross;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nhx59/2/

or use a image http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-symbols

Answer (score 0):

There is another way.
In my labelFormatter, i return a html string which includes my image, with a unique class name or id.

Now, I listen for legendItemClick event under plotOptions.column.events or plotOptions.line.events and then find my  element and add a css class which has opacity in it like below:`.dullImage {
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* msie */
}`

In the legendItemClick, event object is passed and you can look at event.currentTarget.name (to find legend name) and event.currentTarget.isDirty to determine if this was click to disable or enable legend.

Answer (score 0):

You can Easley add icons or font awesome in legends with text.

```
series: [{
  type: 'pie',
  name: '',
  data: [
    ['<i class="fa fa-edit"></i>  Saved ', 40],
    ['<i class="fa fa-hourglass-o"></i>  Pending ', 60,],
    ['<i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>  Approved ', 20],
    ['<i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>  Rejected ', 20],
  ],
  dataLabels: {
    useHTML: true
  },
  animation: true
}],
```

See Complete working article with demo on link https://w3reign.com/highcharts-legend-with-font-awesome-icon-and-values-inside-plot-area/