# Bubble Chart with ellipse instead of circles

Tags: highcharts, bubble-chart

I was wondering if there's a hack to draw an ellipse instead of a circle. SVG itself does provide an ellipse element, e.g.:

```
<ellipse cx="200" cy="80" rx="100" ry="50">
```

Comment: The ellipse as marker?If yes you need to add this shape to Highcharts.markers.symbols array and then use it. Related topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499558/set-custom-legend-item-symbol-or-icon-in-highcharts

Comment: The ellipse instead of the circular bubbles. The [bubble example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bubble) on the highcharts page uses [x,y,r] to draw circles. I'd need [x,y,rx,ry], which is an ellipse.

Comment: As I mentioned, it is not build-in so you need to develop it on your own.

Comment: This is a good idea to extend the core functionality of highcharts.